# Octave: how to retrieve data from a Java ResultSet object?

Tags: octave, resultset, ojdbc

I need to feed my Octave instance with data retrieved from an Oracle database.

I have implemented an OJDBC connection in my Octave instance an I am able now to put data from an Oracle database into a Java ResultSet object in Octave (taken from: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2011-08/msg00250.html):

```
javaaddpath('access-path-to-ojdbc8.jar') ;
props = javaObject('java.util.Properties') ;
props.setProperty("user", 'username') ;
props.setProperty("password", 'password') ;
driver = javaObject('oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver') ;
url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:schema' ;
con = driver.connect(url, props) ;
sql = 'select-query' ;
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql) ;
rs = ps.executeQuery() ;
```

But haven't succeeded with retrieving data from that ResultSet.

How can I put data from a ResultSet object in Octave into an array or matrix?

Comment: Please create a minimal example for specific help. But in general, the java interface for octave can be found here: https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/Java-Interface.html#Java-Interface

Comment: are you looking for a way howto parse a JSON result?

Comment: @Andy I don't know what kind of data structure the ResultSet is. Anyway, I'd rather not parse its content word by word, but instead learn a seamless solution of how to put the content into an Octave object like array or matrix. If there is one. There is one in R for example.

Comment: @Tasos Added my code.

Comment: The `ResultSet` will be an object that implements the [`java.sql.ResultSet` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html). You don't need to (and shouldn't care about) the exact type it actually is; just code against the `java.sql.ResultSet` interface API instead.

Answer (score 1):

### Finding out what to do

The docs you want for `ResultSet` and related classes are in the [Java JDBC API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/). (You don't need the Oracle-specific doco unless you want to do fancy Oracle-specific stuff. All JDBC drivers conform to the generic JDBC API.) Have a look at that and any JDBC tutorial; because it is a Java object, you'll use all the same method calls from Octave that you would from Java code.

For conversion to Octave values, know that Java primitives convert to Octave types automatically, `java.lang.String` objects require conversion by calling `char(...)` on them, and `java.sql.Date` values you will have to convert to `datenums` manually. (Lazy way is to get their string values and parse them; fast way is to get their Unix time values and convert numerically.)

### What to do

Because Java JDBC advances the result set cursor one row at a time, and requires a separate method call to get the value for each column, you need to use a pair of nested loops to iterate over the ResultSet. Like this:

```
rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
nCols = rsMeta.getColumnCount();
data = NaN(1, nCols);
iRow = 0;
while rs.next()
  iRow = iRow + 1;
  for iCol = 1:nCols
    data(iRow,iCol) = rs.getDouble(iCol);
  endfor
endwhile
```

Ah, but what if your columns aren't all numerics? Then you'll need to look at the column type in `rsMeta`, switch on it, and use a cell array to hold the heterogeneous data set. Like this:

```
rsMeta = rs.getMetaData();
nCols = rsMeta.getColumnCount();
data = cell(1, nCols);
iRow = 0;
while rs.next()
  iRow = iRow + 1;
  for iCol = 1:nCols
    colTypeId = rsMeta.getColumnType(iCol);
    switch colTypeId
      case NUMERIC_TYPE
        data{iRow,iCol} = rs.getDouble(iCol);
      case CHAR_TYPE
        data{iRow,iCol} = rs.getString(iCol);
        data{iRow,iCol} = char(data{iRow,iCol});
      # ... and so on ...
      otherwise
        error('Unsupported SQL data type in column %d: %d', ...
          iCol, colTypeId);
    endswitch
  endfor
endwhile
```

How do you know what the values for `NUMERIC_TYPE`, `CHAR_TYPE`, and so on should be? You have to examine the values in the `java.sql.Types` Java class. Do that at run time to make sure you're consistent with the JDK you're running against.

(Note: this code is the easy, sloppy way of doing it. There's all sorts of improvements and optimizations you could (and should) do on it.)

### How to go fast

Unfortunately, the performance of this is going to *suck big time*, because Java method calls from Octave are expensive, and cells are in inefficient way of holding data. If your result sets are large, in order to get good performance, what you need to do is write a result set buffering layer *in Java* that runs the loops in Java and buffers the results in primitive per-column arrays, and use that. If you want an example of how to do this, I have [an example implementation in Matlab in my Janklab library](https://github.com/apjanke/janklab/tree/c45c9af0571748362c1e245227ef800ca0e64443/src/java/janklab-java/src/main/java/net/janklab/mdbc) (M-code layer [here](https://github.com/apjanke/janklab/tree/c45c9af0571748362c1e245227ef800ca0e64443/Mcode/classes/%2Bjl/%2Bmdbc)). Feel free to steal the code. Octave doesn't support dot-referencing of Java constructors or class methods, so to convert it to Octave, you'd need to replace all those with `javaObject` and `javaMethod` calls. (That's tedious and results in ugly code, so I'm not going to do it myself. Sorry.)

If you're not willing to do that (and really, who is?), and still need good performance, what you should *actually* do is forget about connecting Octave directly to Oracle, and write a separate Python/NumPy or R program that takes your query, runs it against your Oracle db, and writes the result to a `.mat` file that you will then read from Octave.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the specified .jar or a suitable database to test your specific code, but in any case, this isn't really a problem of octave. Effectively you need the relevant api for the ResultSet class, and a standard approach for processing it. The oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/JDBC-getting-started.html#GUID-C7FAF579-24DB-4682-BC83-44AC5E59A8D8) suggests that in java you'd do something like this:

```java
while (rs.next()) { System.out.println (rs.getString(1)); }
```

So, presumably this is exactly what you'll do in octave too, except via octave's java interface. One possible way this might look like is

```matlab
while rs.next().booleanValue  % since a Boolean java object by itself
                              % isn't valid logical input for octave's
                              % 'while' statement
    % do something with rs, e.g. fill in a cell array
endwhile
```

As for whether you can automatically convert a java array to an octave cell-object or vice-versa, as far as I know this is not possible. You'd have to set / get elements from one to the other via a for loop, just like you'd do in java (e.g. see the note in the manual regarding the [javaArray](https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/Java-Interface-Functions.html#XREFjavaArray) function)

Comment: "since a Boolean java object by itself" – `rs.next()` returns a primitive `boolean`, not a `Boolean` object, so it is autoboxed (automatically converted) by Octave into a `logical`. You don't need to call `booleanValue()`, and in fact it will not work.